# Почему происходит ошибка "got an unexpected keyword argument" при использовании параметра min_frequency в OneHotEncoder?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, sklearn

Пытаюсь в `OneHotEncoder` использовать параметр `min_frequency`, что бы при кодировке сгруппировать редкие категории, так как данных очень много, но получаю ошибку:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_frequency'
```

В документации про это свойство написано, в каких то инструкциях в инете - тоже, но у меня при использовании выдает ошибку. Когда с помощью `.get_params().keys()` смотрю возможные параметры объекта `OneHotEncoder`, то в этом списке нет `min_frequency`. Ощущение, что оно уже не используется.. Может есть аналог какой то? Или остается только написать функцию для моей цели?